# can anyone explain me why the answer is { name : 'Linda'};

Tags: javascript, object

```
let person = { name : 'Linda'};
let members = person;
person = null

console.log(members)
```

the output is {name: 'Linda'}
but what i've learnt about reference type is that members and person have the same memory address

Comment: "members and person have the same memory address" - are you saying the 2 _named variables_ point to the same memory address - or are you saying the 2 of them have the same value (i.e. they both reference the same object)?

Comment: You have two pieces of paper telling you where you left your car keys. You cross one out and write "null" on it. You read the other - what will you find at the location it tells you to look?

Comment: _"what i've learnt about reference type is that members and person have the same memory address"_ - this `person = null` doesn't clears the memory that is occupied by the object that both `person` and `members` refer to; it only clears the address of the object that is held by the `person` whereas `members` still has a reference to the object.

Comment: Thank you guys, I got it.

Answer (score 4):

> ...but what i've learnt about reference type is that members and person have the same memory address...

Sort of. They both contain a reference to the same object, which is elsewhere in memory (not literally inside the variables). *(Whether that's literally a memory address or whatever is an implementation detail you don't need to care about, and may differ from JavaScript engine to JavaScript engine.)*

When you do `person = null`, all you're doing is clearing that reference out of the `person` variable. Doing that has no effect at all on `members` or on the object that it refers to.

Let's do this step by step:

```
let person = { name : 'Linda'};
```

To handle that, the JavaScript engine creates an object in memory. That object will have some kind of way to refer to it called an object reference. For our purposes, let's say it's `Ref1234` (that name has **no** underlying meaning, I literally just picked it at random so we had a name to use):

```
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
Ref1234−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>|   (object)    |
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                        | name: "Linda" |
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Then the JavaScript engine stores that reference in the variable `person`:

```
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
Ref1234−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−>|   (object)    |
                  |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  |     | name: "Linda" |
                  |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
person:  Ref1234 −+
```

Then we do:

```
let members = person;
```

Which just copies the reference in `person` into `members` as well:

```
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
Ref1234−−−−−−−−−−−+−+−−>|   (object)    |
                  | |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  | |   | name: "Linda" |
                  | |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
person:  Ref1234 −+ |
                    |
members: Ref1234 −−−+
```

Then we do:

```
person = null;
```

All that does is put `null` in `person`:

```
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
Ref1234−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−>|   (object)    |
                    |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                    |   | name: "Linda" |
                    |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
person:  null       |
                    |
members: Ref1234 −−−+
```

That doesn't change anything else at all. So

```
console.log(members)
```

shows the object.

**If** you then did `members = null;` or the `members` variable went out of scope with no closure retaining it, etc., and **if** it was the only remaining thing containing Ref1234, then the object could be garbage-collected by the JavaScript engine. But that doesn't happen when you do `person = null;` because something else (`members`) has a copy of the reference.

Comment: thank you, it's very helpful ! Could you give me some documentation source of how javascript work ?, the tutorial just gave me the datatypes, var, function, etc but did not explain how the js runs. I'm a fresher.

Comment: @Phucq.ins - The specification covers it, but isn't beginner-friendly. I'd suggest *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* by David Flanagan. As a side note: This isn't specific to JavaScript, there are **lots** of languages that work this way: JavaScript, Java, C#, PHP, ... But it's **not** universal. For instance, C++ handles this quite differently (distinguishing between pointer variables and non-pointer variables, and handling them in different ways).

Comment: That's why I feel confused when diving into JavaScript thought i've learnt C++ before, It's hard to handle a new thing. Anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: Ah! Yes, a bit of a different beast. When referring to objects, JavaScript (and Java and C# and PHP) variables are more like C++'s pointer variables (`Thing *pt`) than like the other kind (`Thing t`). That should help some. :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

When you assign person to members, member will store the address of person at this moment. Then you assign person to null so that person will point to another address but not change the value of existed address. So members still keep the old address and its value

Comment: "*the address of person*" - that sounds like you're taking the address of a variable

Comment: But this is wrong, it's exactly the confusion that led to the OP's question. JS never takes the address of a variable. There is no reference to the variable.

Comment: I tried to fix it for you because I can see you were trying to fix it, but the edit would have been too large, effectively rewriting the entire answer. I rolled back your edit, though, which made it worse rather than better.